# Clicking on 'Documents & Lists' on top navigation gives error [SP 2003]

Tags: list, error, document, 2003

[image]**When i click on top navigation bar option ' Documents & Lists' of a SP2003 site, its gives me a  general error.** 
But when i click on left navigation option for 'Documents', its loading correctly.

**Top navigation URL : _layout/1033/viewlists.aspx**     - Gives error
**Left navigation URL : _layout/1033/viewlists.aspx?basetype=1**  - loads correctly.

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the SQL services on the servers (WFEs & DB ) resolved this error.